# I keep getting this python error when running any command with pip

Tags: python

I am trying to install packages with pip but every time I run a command this error pops up, I have tried repairing Python but still can not get it to work. I'm new to coding python so I'm not really sure what to do here. Thanks.

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\sachl\.windows-build-tools\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 174, in _run_module_as_main
    "__main__", fname, loader, pkg_name)
  File "C:\Users\sachl\.windows-build-tools\python27\lib\runpy.py", line 72, in _run_code
    exec code in run_globals
  File "C:\Users\sachl\.windows-build-tools\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\__main__.py", line 21, in <module>
    from pip._internal.cli.main import main as _main
  File "C:\Users\sachl\.windows-build-tools\python27\lib\site-packages\pip\_internal\cli\main.py", line 60
    sys.stderr.write(f"ERROR: {exc}")
                                   ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Comment: Are you trying to use Python 3?  Also when you say you are running commands, do you mean pip commands?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like there's a confusion of Python versions; the filenames suggest Python 2.7 (directory name `python27`), but the code is Python 3.6 or later (strings prefixed with `f"`, known as [f-strings](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/inputoutput.html#formatted-string-literals)).

You'll need to reinstall matching versions of python and pip; probably the latest (Python 3.x), unless you have reason to use 2.7 specifically.